# ASP.NET Confirm Box During Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a HttpPost - JsonResult typed a method.
In the middle of method, i need a confirm from user. I will continue according to response from user.

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult SepeteAt(int urunID, int subeID, int miktar)
{
  // some codes

  if (somethings happens) then    
  // *** SHOW CONFIRM BOX ***

  if (response == true)
  { // do somethings }
  else
  { // do somethings }

  // some codes
}
```

as i said, i need to get response in the middle of method.
How can i success it? Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can show confirm box by sending message with `return Json(message)` and put `confirm(result.message)` in client-side `success` AJAX callback, depending on your requirements (please explain more details).

Comment: You cannot display a 'confirm' box in the server. You need to return a result back to the client indicating if a message needs to be displayed (e.g. `return Json(new { ShowMessage = true, Message = "...." });`